# How to remove a specific string in a json file?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to remove a specific String from a JsonObject, Can you tell me what is wrong with my code. after executing it it still contains what i try to remove.

This my Json structure:

> { "telNumbers":[{"Telephone":"01285354562","Id":"234"}, 
>   {"Telephone":"001225254542","Id":"235"} ]}

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        File jSonfile = new File(loader.searchPath("call_data") + "telNumbers.json");
        JSONArray jsoArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jSonfile.toString()));
            jsoArray.add(obj);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsoArray.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Before --" + jsoArray.get(i).toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsoArray.get(i);
                jsonObject.remove(id);
                jsonObject.remove(num);
                // jsonObject .remove("empty");
                System.out.println("Logic.RootController.deleteJsonElement()");
                System.out.println("After --" + jsoArray.get(i).toString());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RootController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

Comment: Where are you getting id and num in your jsonObject.remove? Not seeing those defined anywhere. It looks like you are tryingto remove something with a specific value? Is that correct?

Comment: I am getting them as a user input through a method parameter

Comment: What does it mean to remove a string from an object? An object contains key-value pairs. Show an example with `id`,`num` and your expected result.